# Developing a new application on centos

Tags: linux, centos

I am developing an application in centos which requires usage of many linux utilities like *rsync* n *ssh*. Please suggest a tool or a platform for it.

Comment: What is the question? Just develop that application, and fork as needed the relevant processes....

Answer (score 1):

Just write it in C and use the fork syscall, this is used to create a new process, which you can redirect the stdin/out of.

Comment: You'll also need to use `pipe`, and probably `poll`

Comment: Correction: I have to make a GUI to run these commands as back end

Comment: So, use fork to run the commands, and read stdout and use the gui to output according to what stdout is saying.